# chmod for Local Folder OK but Network Folder NG

Tags: php

I have 2 source like this :

```
$source = "C:\test\bla.txt";

$source2 = "\\\\192.168.182.20\\test\\bla.txt";
```

When I tried to chmod variable `$source`, it's ok. But when tried chmod `$source2` it show error like this :

```
Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: No such file or directory in...
```

Actually I want to copy file from `$source` to `$source2` but got error like this :

```
Warning: copy(\\192.168.182.20\test\bla.txt) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in...
```

I already set for test folder to be full access for every one and shared it.

Please help to advice!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's too many (and incorrect) slashes in `source2` I believe, in fact, you'd probably want it to look like this instead:

```
$source2 = "http://192.168.182.20/test/bla.txt"
```

Comment: I'm not using http. Local folder actually like : \\192.168.183.20 to access the folder and file

Comment: I think the slashes are still too many... have you tried with only 2 at the beginning and then only one in the rest of the path...? also, your 2 errors are not the same, the first one is probably about the above incorrect formatting, while the 2nd is a permission issue...